# Derivative of HeunC function

Tags: special-functions, maple

Given the HeunC function:
$$
\operatorname{HeunC}\left( \frac{a^2}{2} \sqrt{2k+3},-1/2,-1+\frac{a^2}{2},-\frac{a^2}{8}(-1 +a^2 k), \frac{1}{2}-\frac{a^2}{4}, -\frac{x^2}{a^2} \right)
$$
where $a$ is an arbitrary constant and $k$ is an arbitrary positive constant, what is the derivative of this function with respect to $x$?

Comment: Try HeunCPrime() http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=HeunC

Comment: @BrianTupper I have edited the question to use MathJax and to specify that the derivative with respect to $x$ is needed.

Comment: I have added the Maple tag, as the syntax in the question leads me to believe that this is a maple question, although I may be mistaken.

Comment: @Ed, actually, one can now combine your pointer with the chain rule to give an answer to this question...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the derivative of your function with respect to $x$ computed by Maple,

$$\frac{d}{dx} {\it HeunC} \left( A,B,C,D,E,-{\frac {{x}^{2}}{{a}^{2}}}
 \right)  = - \frac{2x}{a^2}{\it HeunCPrime} \left( A,B,C,D,E,-{\frac {{x}^{2}}{{a}^{2}}}
 \right) 
$$
where HeunCPrime The derivative of the Heun Confluent function.

Comment: Why is the $x$ in the denominator?

Comment: @J.M:Typing error. Thanks.